# Insert textbox and datagridview correctly c# sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

I am working with a small POS application , and after the payment data are stored into two tables. From the form data are stored into two tables from two group of data :

1. Textboxes (general data like date, worker , total etc)-- saved in table 1
2. Datagridview (Product informations like code, name, qty , price etc) -- saved in table

Data are being stored into each tables, for in table one there are much rows inserted as the datagridview has rows. To be clearer: if datagridview has 5 rows stored in tables 2, there are also 5 rows stored in table one with same data repeated from textboxes.

The code I used to insert is showed below:

```
try
{
     conn.Open();

     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikuj.Rows)
     {
          if (!row.IsNewRow)
          {
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertfaturimi", conn);
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nrfatures", int.Parse(txtnrfatures.Text)));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@klienti",  cmbklienti.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shenime", txtshenime.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pagesa", faturimi));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nentotali", txttotali.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zbritje", txtzbritja.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totali", totali.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvsh", textBox1.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nrartikujve", lblnumri.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@kasieri", lbluser.Text));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@koha", DateTime.Now));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barkodi", row.Cells[0].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emertimi", row.Cells[1].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sasia", row.Cells[2].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tvsh", row.Cells[3].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmimi", row.Cells[4].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totalipcs", row.Cells[5].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vlerapatvshpcs", row.Cells[6].Value));
              cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleraetvshpcs", row.Cells[7].Value));

              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Faturimi deshtoi" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        clear();
        button5.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

And the stored procedure I used is shown below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertfaturimi]
    @nrfatures int,
    @barkodi int,
    @emertimi varchar (max),
    @sasia int,
    @tvsh float,
    @cmimi float,
    @totalipcs float,
    @vlerapatvshpcs float,
    @vleraetvshpcs float,
    @klienti varchar(100),
    @pagesa varchar (200),
    @shenime varchar (200),
    @nrartikujve int,
    @vleratvsh float,
    @nentotali float,
    @zbritje float,
    @totali float,
    @kasieri varchar(50),
    @koha datetime
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_faturimi(ID_FATURES, Klienti, Shenime, Pagesa, Nentotali, Zbritja, Totali, VleraTVSH, NR_artikujve, Kasieri, Data) 
    VALUES (@nrfatures, @klienti, @shenime, @pagesa, @nentotali, @zbritje, @totali, @vleratvsh, @nrartikujve, @kasieri, @koha)

    INSERT INTO tblfaturimi_details (NR_FATURES, Barkodi, Emertimi, Cmimi, Sasia, TVSH, Totali, VleraeTVSH, VleraPaTVSH)
    VALUES (@nrfatures, @barkodi, @emertimi, @cmimi, @sasia, @tvsh, @totalipcs, @vleraetvshpcs, @vlerapatvshpcs)
END
```

I think the error is from the loop , because inside the loop is also the textbox included not just the datagridview. I tried to put the code that insert the textboxes outside the loop, but I get an error:

> Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Could some one tell what to change in code.

Thank you!

Comment: I would start by using a new `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object for each iteration, and make sure they are both disposed of correctly by putting them in `using` blocks. There is no benefit to re-using these objects, as .net will use connection pooling under the hood anyway. I am no expert, but I expect that due to not disposing of the SqlCommand properly, and re-using the same connection the parameters are remaining in a cache somewhere, so when you add more parameters in the next iteration you have too many

Comment: @GarethD any example from the code above. If you could help me